# I saved the geletinious material from roasting the turkey. Is this appropriate for use in turkey soup?

Tags: soup

I saved the gelatinous material from roasting a turkey. Is it appropriate to use this when making turkey soup?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is appropriate, and should be used within five days for freshness.

The gelatinous material from roasting the turkey is often used to make homemade bone broth soup.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, assuming that it has been properly refrigerated, it should make fine soup.